# Emulate the behavior of INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger on table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

I've written a trigger like

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON myTable
EXECUTE PROCEDURE myFunction();
```

but I've learned that the `INSTEAD OF` trigger cannot be applied to a table.

The only way to do it should be by using

```
BEFORE OF INSERT
```

the trigger should retrieve some values (unknown when the user calls the insert function) on the other table and insert this value inside firing query and execute it. How can I do this?

Comment: If you're going to [post multiple questions in rapid succession](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170508/create-trigger-instead-of-issue-tables-cannot-have-instead-of-triggers/18170770#18170770) please **link back to your earlier questions**. You should also always mention your PostgreSQL version in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You would write a PL/PgSQL trigger that:

- Checks `tg_op` to determine whether the operation is an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`; and
- Based on the operation type, uses the `NEW` and/or `OLD` pseudo-variables to construct and run `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s, or `DELETE`s on the real target tables; then
- Return `NULL` so that no action is taken on the original target table.

See [the basic documentation on PL/PgSQL triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).

This is a pretty weird thing to want to do unless you're using table inheritance, though.